# Not able to place conditional check on download button

Tags: r, shiny

I want to place a conditional check on a download button `btnDownload`. If a particular dataframe `recData$dfData()` has no data, then on clicking the download button, it must show an alert: "A report can't be download due no data present."

```
observeEvent(input$btnDownload, {

  if (nrow(recData$dfData()) != 0) {
    output$btnDownload <- downloadHandler(
      "rpa foundary.docx",
      content = function(file) {
        trycatch(
          expr = {

            if (file.exists("rpa foundary.docx")) {
              file.remove("rpa foundary.docx")
            }

            mydoc <- CreateReportDoc(recData$dfData(), recData$dfProjectWeeklyDtls())

            print(mydoc, file)
            print(mydoc, file, target = "rpa foundary.docx")
            shinyalert(
              type = "success",
              title = "download complete!", 
              text = paste0("report downloaded successfully")
            )
          }, error = function(e) {
            logerror(e, fxname = "btnDownload", app = "server.r")
          }, warning = function(w){
            logwarning(w, fxname = "btnDownload", app = "server.r")
          }
        )}## downloader   
      )} else {
        shinyalert(
          type = "error", title = "report cannot be downloaded!",
          text = paste0("no data available to display")
        )
      }
    })
```

I was expecting only alert when `recData$dfData()` has no data. But i am getting `![c:Libraries\Pictures\dwnld.png]` html document download.

Comment: I think this is overly complicated. When you click the Button, the dataframe seems to be already calculated. Why not disable the button dependend on the number of rows and change the Text of the button?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @DSGym, I would rather disable the button when the data is not available. We can also add a tooltip to provide info to the user.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  br(),br(),
  div(id="dwnbutton", 
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download", disabled = "disabled")
  ),
  br(), br(),
  actionButton("go", "Go")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset - empty at initialisation
  data <- reactiveVal(data.frame())

  observeEvent(input[["go"]], {
    data(mtcars)
  })

  observeEvent(data(), {
    if(nrow(data()) > 0){
      enable("downloadData")
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').removeAttr('title');")
    }else{
      disable("downloadData")
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').attr('title', 'Data not available');")
    }
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

If you really want an alert, here is a way.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  br(),br(),
  div(id="dwnbutton", 
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download", 
                     onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('dwnClicked', true, {priority:'event'});")
  ),
  br(), br(),
  actionButton("go", "Go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Our dataset - empty at initialisation
  data <- reactiveVal(data.frame())

  observeEvent(input[["go"]], {
    data(mtcars)
  })

  observeEvent(data(), {
    if(nrow(data()) > 0){
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').off('click.x');")
    }else{
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').on('click.x', function(e){e.preventDefault();});")
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input[["dwnClicked"]], {
    if(nrow(data()) == 0){
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "No data !",
        text = "No data available",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

But at least I would add a style to the button to show that the data is not available:

```
  observeEvent(data(), {
    if(nrow(data()) > 0){
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').off('click.x');")
      runjs("$('#downloadData').removeClass('btn-danger');")
    }else{
      runjs("$('#dwnbutton').on('click.x', function(e){e.preventDefault();});")
      runjs("$('#downloadData').addClass('btn-danger');")
    }
  })
```

[image]

Comment: i used your alert code in which i am getting sweet alert but also getting a download of `btnDownload.htm` on clicking the button which i dont want .

Comment: @aqqi I don't see what you mean. My code does not do that. Perhaps edit your post to show what you have done.